# Use custom client protocol for pytest

Tags: pytest, locust

I'm trying to use locust as a pytest library to write stress tests, but I have encountered some problems, and I can't solve them after several hours.
There are some assert statements in my pytest. I hope that when the assert statement reports an error, the locust will be stopped immediately and the test will be marked as failed.

```
class StressRobot(User):
    wait_time = between(0.01, 0.1)
    __robot = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @task
    def execute(self):
        try:
            logging.debug("do some stress test")
            assert False
        except Exception as e:
            events.request_failure.fire()

@pytest.mark.stress
def test():
    env = Environment(user_classes=[StressRobot])
    env.create_local_runner()
    env.runner.start(10, spawn_rate=10)
    gevent.spawn_later(5, lambda: env.runner.quit())
    env.runner.greenlet.join()

    assert env.stats.num_failures == 0
```

My code is like the above. I hope that when assert False, the pytest case will end immediately, and assert env.stats.num_failures == 0 will report an error. But he is not over, he will keep running, keep reporting errors, and will not end until 5 seconds later, and finally env.stats.num_failures == 0

Answer (score 0):

A failure does not stop a locust run.

In your task you can call self.environment.runner.quit() (instead of just logging a request failure event)

See https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#environment-attribute